# How to anchor an HTML element in the center between two other elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please, observe this simple jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/vtLrt/10/

HTML:

```
<div class="char">
  <div>
    <div class="char">A1</div>
    <div class="char anchorToMiddle">D1</div>
    <div class="char anchorToRight">G1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="char">A2</div>
    <div class="char anchorToMiddle">D2</div>
    <div class="char anchorToRight">G2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="char">A3</div>
    <div class="char">B3</div>
    <div class="char">C3</div>
    <div class="char">D3</div>
    <div class="char">E3</div>
    <div class="char">F3</div>
    <div class="char">G3</div>
  </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.char{
    display: inline-block;
}


.anchorToRight {
    float: right;
}​
```

Output:

[image]

How can I change the HTML and/or CSS, so that the elements marked as `anchorToMiddle` (D1 and D2) be aligned in the middle, right above D3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to find a solution with some javascript (since the question was tagged with javascript).

If you set text-align to "center" in "anchorToMiddle" the text will be centered but only if you specify the element's width. To do this, B3..F3 are wrapped inside another div (with id "charspan"):

```
<div id="charspan" class="char">
    <div class="char">B3</div>
    <!-- etc. -->
</div>
```

then this new div's width is calculated and applied to the class "anchorToMiddle".

```
var elems, i, width, span;
elems = document.getElementsByClassName("anchorToMiddle");
span = document.getElementById("charspan");
width = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(span).width);
for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].style.width = width + 'px';
}
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Espesen/vtLrt/14/

Comment: I wished there was an HTML/CSS only solution. But, at the absense of other options...

Answer (score 1):

If you give it a proper width and then use `text-align:center;` property, it should get fixed.

I have updated your [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vtLrt/11/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.anchorToMiddle
{
  width:someWidthValue less than parent;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: So, a javascript is needed to calculate `someWidthValue`?

Comment: Umm, I don't know. Its your page. Is the width of that div based on the width of something else or is it constant?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make a 3x7 table instead?

```
<table>

    <tr>

        <td>A1</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>G1</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>A2</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>D2</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>G2</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>A3</td>
        <td>B3</td>
        <td>C3</td>
        <td>D3</td>
        <td>E3</td>
        <td>F3</td>
        <td>G3</td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: The data is not tabular. A1, A2, ... are there to make the example simple. In reality they are div blocks with fields.